# Зачем делают проверку ref в useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

На сколько я знаю ref присваивается в тот же момент когда и вызывается синхронный useLayoutEffect, то есть в useLayoutEffect - ref уже доступен, но я не понимаю почему даже эксперты с фриланса пишут проверки на ref.current в useEffect - который асинхронный и отрабатывает намного позже чем useLayoutEffect, кто-то может дать внятный ответ на мой вопрос ? Может я где-то ошибаюсь ?

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
   const ref = useRef(null);

   useEffect(() => {
     if(ref.current){// зачем это тут ?
       console.log(ref.current)
     }
   }, [])

   return <div ref={ref}>hello</div>
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: А вы пробовали без проверки?

Comment: Конкретно в твоем примере проверка не нужна. Функция в `useEffect` без параметров будет вызвана уже после того как `Component` будет смонтирован на странице и в `ref` уже будет ссылка на `<div ref={ref}>hello</div>`...